# Web API 2.0 Routing with only one variable segment (for input parameter)

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a simple route of the form (In the following route templates "param" is the only variable):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
    name: "RouteName",
    routeTemplate: "/ActionName/{param}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" }
);
```

(param is not optional).

To make things simple, this is the only route in my `WebApiConfig.Register()` method. And no, there's no call to `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`

Yet it seems the route is not found when called like:

```
localhost:xxx/ActionName/?param=blah
```

or

```
localhost:xxx/ActionName/blah
```

Just to see what happens if I have my route defined like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute (
    name: "RouteName",
    routeTemplate: "Controller/ActionName/{param}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" }
);
```

and called like this:

```
localhost:xxx/Controller/ActionName/?param=blah
```

or

```
localhost:xxx/Controller/ActionName/blah
```

and still no joy. Am I missing something or does Web API not map a controller using a defaults object?

Comment: Show an example of the controller and action you are trying to map to as it relates to the example above. Please format your question properly as it is currently difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Nkosi.

Unfortunately, I can't post the actual code due to confidentiality. I was getting 404 - not found in the problem I was trying to solve.

Turns out if I add "param" to my defaults object as follows:
new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", param = RouteParameter.Optional }

(even though it is a required parameter) then everything works. Unless I do that, I can't use a query string format with a named parameter

localhost:xxx/ActionName/?param=blah

If I Omit it, then I must use a segmented pattern as follows:

localhost:xxx/ActionName/blah

Thanks again for wanting to look at it.